# Calculating the lat and lon from given kilometer

Tags: latitude-longitude

I am trying to calculate the latitude and longitude from the given radius. Eg: If my latitude and longitude is 1.234 and 2.345. 5KM is the radius. What will the latitude and longitude after 5KM ? I have no idea how to calculate this. Please help me out.

Comment: You can’t just have “5km” - that’s a circle.  You also need a direction (eg an angle where 0 degrees is due north)

Comment: Take a look at https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html section “ Destination point given distance and bearing from start point”